# Popup refusing to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I made a practice webpage to familiarize myself with HTML and CSS.

Everything on it works except the popup, which refuses to fire in Chrome and Opera for unknown reasons (can't test in Firefox, as the images don't load, probably because they're being pulled straight from my computer because I can't be bothered to upload them to the internet).

According to Chrome, the Javascript function isn't defined- but it is. So what's going on here?

In case anyone was wondering, the popup works fine on an otherwise blank page- it's only when I put it on the page it's intended for that it has issues.

ALSO: if there's a way to consolidate all the code for the images, that would be fantastic.

Here's the code:

```js
function openClosePopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 968px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
}

#header {
  background: #181818;
  height: 78px;
  width: 968px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  background: black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 968px;
  border-top: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul {
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #E6E6E6;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  background: #090909;
  width: 968px;
  height: 4080px;
}

.popup .popupContent {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s
}

#MV,
#PI {
  background: black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 968px;
  border-top: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#MV ul {
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

img.ReallyReally {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

img.Fool {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 279px;
}

img.Body {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 483px;
}

img.BabyBaby {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.Sent {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 311px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

img.ImYoung {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 311px;
  margin-left: 279px;
}

img.ImHim {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 311px;
  margin-left: 483px;
}

img.Empty {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 311px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.ColorRing {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 618px;
  margin-left: 380px;
}

img.ReallyReally,
img.Fool,
img.Body,
img.BabyBaby,
img.Sent,
img.ImYoung,
img.ImHim,
img.ColorRing,
img.Empty {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

img.ReallyReally:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Fool:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Body:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.BabyBaby:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Sent:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ImYoung:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ImHim:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ColorRing:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Empty:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#PI {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1072px;
}

#PI ul {
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#Section2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 33px;
}

img.FateNumInnCirc {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 925px;
}

img.FateNumInnCirc:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.FateNumConcept {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 925px;
}

img.FateNumConcept:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.FoolPoster {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 925px;
}

img.FoolPoster:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ReallyReallyPoster {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 925px;
}

img.ReallyReallyPoster:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.FateNumCovTease {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 1229px;
}

img.FateNumCovTease:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ExitTour {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 1229px;
}

img.ExitTour:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Babyx2Poster {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 1231px;
}

img.Babyx2Poster:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ImYoungPoster {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 1233px;
}

img.ImYoungPoster:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.SentPoster {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 1533px;
}

img.SentPoster:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PreRelease {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 1537px;
}

img.PreRelease:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ExitETrack {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 1539px;
}

img.ExitETrack:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Pricked {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 1541px;
}

img.Pricked:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ExitPlan {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 1841px;
}

img.ExitPlan:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ExitNewRelease {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 1845px;
}

img.ExitNewRelease:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.DimensionPremiere {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 1847px;
}

img.DimensionPremiere:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.ImHimPoster {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 1849px;
}

img.ImHimPoster:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.DebutMV {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 2149px;
}

img.DebutMV:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.SSTracklist {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 2149px;
}

img.SSTracklist:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Debut {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 2203px;
}

img.Debut:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.GrandLaunch {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 2157px;
}

img.GrandLaunch:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.WinnerWeek {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 2508px;
}

img.WinnerWeek:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT5Group {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 2508px;
}

img.PT5Group:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT5Jinwoo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 2562px;
}

img.PT5Jinwoo:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT5NamTae {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 2444px;
}

img.PT5NamTae:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT5Yoon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 2645px;
}

img.PT5Yoon:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT5Mino {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 2637px;
}

img.PT5Mino:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT5Hoony {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 2677px;
}

img.PT5Hoony:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT4Group {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 2573px;
}

img.PT4Group:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT4Jinwoo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 2761px;
}

img.PT4Jinwoo:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT4NamTae {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 2816px;
}

img.PT4NamTae:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT4Yoon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 2806px;
}

img.PT4Yoon:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT4Mino {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 2727px;
}

img.PT4Mino:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT4Hoony {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 2890px;
}

img.PT4Hoony:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT3Group {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 2945px;
}

img.PT3Group:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT3Jinwoo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 2985px;
}

img.PT3Jinwoo:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT3NamTae {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 687px;
  margin-top: 2855px;
}

img.PT3NamTae:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT3Yoon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 3069px;
}

img.PT3Yoon:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT3Mino {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-top: 3099px;
}

img.PT3Mino:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT3Group2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 483px;
  margin-top: 3101px;
}

img.PT3Group2:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT2Group {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3010px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.PT2Group:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT2Jinwoo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3223px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

img.PT2Jinwoo:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT2NamTae {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3215px;
  margin-left: 279px;
}

img.PT2NamTae:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT2Yoon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3255px;
  margin-left: 483px;
}

img.PT2Yoon:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT2Mino {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3125px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.PT2Mino:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT2Hoony {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3377px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

img.PT2Hoony:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT1Group {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3332px;
  margin-left: 279px;
}

img.PT1Group:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT1Jinwoo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3372px;
  margin-left: 483px;
}

img.PT1Jinwoo:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT1NamTae {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3242px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.PT1NamTae:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT1Yoon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3494px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

img.PT1Yoon:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT1Mino {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3449px;
  margin-left: 279px;
}

img.PT1Mino:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PT1Hoony {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3489px;
  margin-left: 483px;
}

img.PT1Hoony:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.PTPlan {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3359px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.PTPlan:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Launch {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3648px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

img.Launch:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.WinnerTV {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3603px;
  margin-left: 279px;
}

img.WinnerTV:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.TeamA {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3643px;
  margin-left: 483px;
}

img.TeamA:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.Win {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3654px;
  margin-left: 687px;
}

img.Win:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

img.FateNumInnCirc,
img.FateNumConcept,
img.FoolPoster,
img.ReallyReallyPoster,
img.FateNumCovTease,
img.ExitTour,
img.Babyx2Poster,
img.ImYoungPoster,
img.SentPoster,
img.PreRelease,
img.ExitETrack,
img.Pricked,
img.ExitPlan,
img.ExitNewRelease,
img.DimensionPremiere,
img.ImHimPoster,
img.DebutMV,
img.SSTracklist,
img.Debut,
img.GrandLaunch,
img.WinnerWeek,
img.PT5Group,
img.PT5Jinwoo,
img.PT5NamTae,
img.PT5Yoon,
img.PT5Mino,
img.PT5Hoony,
img.PT4Group,
img.PT4Jinwoo,
img.PT4NamTae,
img.PT4Yoon,
img.PT4Mino,
img.PT4Hoony,
img.PT3Group,
img.PT3Jinwoo,
img.PT3NamTae,
img.PT3Yoon,
img.PT3Mino,
img.PT3Group2,
img.PT2Group,
img.PT2Jinwoo,
img.PT2NamTae,
img.PT2Yoon,
img.PT2Mino,
img.PT2Hoony,
img.PT1Group,
img.PT1Jinwoo,
img.PT1NamTae,
img.PT1Yoon,
img.PT1Mino,
img.PT1Hoony,
img.PTPlan,
img.Launch,
img.WinnerTV,
img.TeamA,
img.Win {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

body {
 background-color: black;
     }

<!--language: lang-html-->

<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="header">
  <p class="logo">
   <img src="C:/Users/kelsey/Pictures/winnerlogo2.png">
  </p>
 </div>

 <div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">HOME</a>
   <li><a href="">ABOUT</a>
   <li><a href="">MEDIA</a>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="content">

  <div id="MV">
   <ul>
    Music Videos
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Section1">
   <div class="popup" onclick="popupOpenClose();"><img class="ReallyReally" src="winnerreallyreallyposter.png">
   <span class="popupContent" id="myPopup"><iframe width="600" height="320"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4tBnF46ybZk?controls=0&showinfo=0" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 350px;" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen></iframe></span>
   </div>

   <img class="Fool" src="winnerfoolposter.png">

   <img class="Body" src="winnerbodyposter.png">

   <img class="BabyBaby" src="winnerbabyx2small.png">

   <img class="Sent" src="winnersentsmall.png">

   <img class="ImYoung" src="winnerimyoungposter.png">

   <img class="ImHim" src="winnerminoimhimposter.png">

   <img class="ColorRing" src="winnercolorringposter.png">

   <img class="Empty" src="winneremptyposter.png">

  </div>

  <div id="PI">
   <ul>
    Promotional Images
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Section2">

   <img class="FateNumInnCirc" src="winnerfatenumforinnercirclesmall.png">

   <img class="FateNumConcept" src="winnerfatenumforconceptsmall.png">

   <img class="FoolPoster" src="winnerfoolposter.png">

   <img class="ReallyReallyPoster" src="winnerreallyreallyposter.png">

   <img class="FateNumCovTease" src="WinnerFateNumForAlbFullSmall.png">

   <img class="ExitTour" src="winnerexittoursmall.png">

   <img class="Babyx2Poster" src="winnerbabyx2small.png">

   <img class="ImYoungPoster" src="winnerimyoungposter.png">

   <img class="SentPoster" src="winnersentsmall.png">

   <img class="PreRelease" src="winnerexitprecovsmall.png"> 

   <img class="ExitETrack" src="winnerexitetracklistsmall.png"> 

   <img class="Pricked" src="winnerprickedsmall.png">

   <img class="ExitPlan" src="winnerexitplansmall.png"> 

   <img class="ExitNewRelease" src="winnerexitnewreleasesmall.png">

   <img class="DimensionPremiere" src="winnerdimensionfilmsmall.png">

   <img class="ImHimPoster" src="winnerminoimhimposter.png">

   <img class="DebutMV" src="winneremptycolorringsmall.png"> 

   <img class="SSTracklist" src="winner2014sstracklistsmall.png">

   <img class="Debut" src="winnerdebutsmall.png">

   <img class="GrandLaunch" src="winnerdebutgrandlaunchsmall.png">

   <img class="WinnerWeek" src="winnerweekplansmall.png">

   <img class="PT5Group" src="winnerpretestgroup5small.png">

   <img class="PT5Jinwoo" src="winnerpretestjinwoo5small.png">

   <img class="PT5NamTae" src="winnerpretestnamtae5small.png">

   <img class="PT5Yoon" src="winnerpretestyoon5small.png">

   <img class="PT5Mino" src="winnerpretestmino5small.png">

   <img class="PT5Hoony" src="winnerpretesthoony5small.png">

   <img class="PT4Group" src="winnerpretestgroup4small.png">

   <img class="PT4Jinwoo" src="winnerpretestjinwoo4small.png">

   <img class="PT4NamTae" src="winnerpretestnamtae4small.png">

   <img class="PT4Yoon" src="winnerpretestyoon4small.png">

   <img class="PT4Mino" src="winnerpretestmino4small.png">

   <img class="PT4Hoony" src="winnerpretesthoony4small.png">

   <img class="PT3Group" src="winnerpretestgroup3small.png">

   <img class="PT3Jinwoo" src="winnerpretestjinwoo3small.png">

   <img class="PT3NamTae" src="winnerpretestnamtae3small.png">

   <img class="PT3Yoon" src="winnerpretestyoon3small.png">

   <img class="PT3Mino" src="winnerpretestmino3small.png">

   <img class="PT3Group2" src="winnerpretestgroup3-2small.png">

   <img class="PT2Group" src="winnerpretestgroup2small.png">

   <img class="PT2Jinwoo" src="winnerpretestjinwoo2small.png">

   <img class="PT2NamTae" src="winnerpretestnamtae2small.png">

   <img class="PT2Yoon" src="winnerpretestyoon2small.png">

   <img class="PT2Mino" src="winnerpretestmino2small.png">

   <img class="PT2Hoony" src="winnerpretesthoony2small.png">

   <img class="PT1Group" src="winnerpretestgroup1small.png">

   <img class="PT1Jinwoo" src="winnerpretestjinwoosmall.png">

   <img class="PT1NamTae" src="winnerpretestnamtaesmall.png">

   <img class="PT1Yoon" src="winnerpretestyoonsmall.png">

   <img class="PT1Mino" src="winnerpretestminosmall.png">

   <img class="PT1Hoony" src="winnerpretesthoonysmall.png">

   <img class="PTPlan" src="winnerpretestplansmall.png">

   <img class="Launch" src="winnerlaunchingplansmall.png">

   <img class="WinnerTV" src="winnertvsmall.png">

   <img class="TeamA" src="winnerteamasmall.png">

   <img class="Win" src="winpostersmall.png">
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: FYI - There is no closing tag for images. `</img>` is invalid HTML. Also,  file paths should not point to an absolute file path (i.e. "C:\...). They should be relative to the current document. Make sure all your syntax is correct before moving on.

Comment: The popup works for me in your snippet.

Comment: I have adjusted the syntax as per your directions. Here is the codepen, where I will update it for now since It doesn't appear that updates can be applied to my original post: https://codepen.io/PeachyPlnk/pen/PmEpmr

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out how to edit the question. The updated HTML is now in the post.